# Using truffle, how to just get the tx hash of a submitted transaction and not wait for the receipt

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I have a token contract that is already deployed, and I am calling the transfer function on the instance.

```
XYZContract.at(ADDRESS).then(instance => {
    return instance.transfer(toAddress, amount);
}).then(result => {
    console.log("transferTokens",result);
    resolve(result);
})
```

Now my understanding is that the 'transfer' promise resolves only after the transaction is recorded into a block.

Is there a way to just get the transaction hash right after submission, but not wait for the receipt?

For e.g web3 has a sendTransaction that fires events when transaction is submitted, transaction receipt is obtained, etc.

In truffle documentation, it's mentioned to use instance.sendTransaction to only send ether 
(https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts). So curious what is the right approach here

My end goal is, I want to run the transfer in a batch and would like to later check using the transaction hashes how many actually succeeded and also the number of confirmations.

Comment: Take a look at my example here: https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/dappathon_demo_front_end/blob/master/js/app.js#L76

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin My understanding is,  the promise for malaysiaInstance.addState() resolves only after the transaction is successfully processed (i.e it's already recorded on to a block with a receipt). My question is, I want to get the tx hash after invoking contract method, and not wait for the receipt

Comment: From further research, the only way I could think of is to use web3's sendTransaction and not rely on truffle's implementation.

Comment: The `malaysiaInstance.addState()` returns a promise with transaction object. That object is transaction that has been pushed into pending transaction pool. It's not yet been mined by the miner. If you're using Ganache GUI, try setting off the auto-mine feature and put 60 seconds mining interval. After you push the transaction, check the receipt using `eth_gettransactionreceipt` -https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionreceipt